# Magnetic dipole interaction from Dirac equation in an external EM Field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, dirac-equation, magnetic-moment

When we multiply the Dirac equation in an external EM Field:
$(i\not\partial - e\not A- m)\psi = 0$

With: $(i\not\partial - e\not A + m)$

We get: $ ((i\partial_\mu - eA_\mu)^2 - e/2F_{\mu\nu}\theta^{\mu\nu} -m^2)\psi$

How can we show that $F_{\mu\nu} \theta^{\mu\nu}$
corresponds to the magnetic dipole interaction?

Comment: maybe use some dollar signs so the equations show up

Comment: The $\theta^{\mu\nu}$ term is the spin tensor term - and would be the Pauli addition. The equation you're trying to solve is the Klein-Gordon-Pauli equation. Maybe you should change the title to the Klein-Gordon-Pauli equation? There are no first order derivatives.$